# Quando e por que usar um construtor parametrizado?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, paradigma-de-programação

Estou muito confuso. Fico me perguntando se é melhor usar o padrão e os setters para atribuir um valor pra o atributo, ou se é melhor atribuir os valores aos atributos via os construtores parametrizados e usar os setters para mudar os estados deles.

Answer (score 4):

A finalidade do construtor é, como o nome diz, construir o objeto. Assim sendo, quando o contrutor retornar, o objeto que for fornecido já deveria estar pronto para uso.

Um objeto está devidamente construído quando todos os seus atributos estão setados para um valor que representa aquilo que o objeto é.

Entretanto, quando usa-se um construtor vazio, esse fornece um esqueleto de um objeto que no estado que está não é utilizável, e então usa-se um monte de setters para consertar-se esse esqueleto. A responsabilidade de construir-se o objeto deveria ser do construtor, mas se ele não fizer isso, essa responsabilidade acabará tendo que ser realizada em algum outro lugar, violando o [princípio da responsabilidade única](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

O resultado disso é uma forma de [acoplamento sequencial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling). Ou seja, o objeto só é utilizável se determinados métodos forem chamados nele.

Deixar o construtor retornar um objeto incompleto a ser consertado depois chamando-se um monte de setters é um **anti-padrão**. Evite fazer isso. Objetos construídos assim são mais difíceis de se manter consistentes, vez que o construtor já os fabrica inconsistentes. Isso significa que há maiores possibilidades de bugs e torna-se mais difícil ler, escrever, entender e alterar o código se necessário.

Além disso, o fato de o construtor abrir mão de construir adequadamente o objeto, praticamente obriga o programador a colocar setters para tudo, mesmo para aquilo que deveriam ser dados e comportamentos internos do objeto, levando a uma violação do encapsulamento.

Comment: Então o certo é construir um objeto com o construtor parametrizado. Pois, o padrão faz um objeto inconsistente, que joga a responsabilidade de atribuir valores a ao objeto nos setter. Estou certo?

Comment: @GilmarSantos Exato.

Comment: Só usarei os setters caso um atributo mude de estado durante a execução do código?

Comment: @GilmarSantos Sim. A ideia é que o setter faça uma mutação no objeto, idealmente de um estado consistente para outro estado consistente. Se o setter for chamado de forma inadequada tentando tornar o objeto inconsistente, lança-se uma exceção. Assim como fazer o objeto nascer inconsistente para ser consertado depois é ruim, permitir que o setter torne-o inconsistente também é. Além disso, você só publica setters para aquilo que faça sentido sofrer mutação.

Comment: É interessante notar que, em Java, criar um construtor não-padrão (com parâmetros) desabilita o construtor padrão automático. Isso é legal porque reforça essa ideia de não deixar o objeto ser criado inconsistente.