# Resultados diferentes com a mesma instrução SQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

Fala programadores(as), tranquilos?

Eu pesquisei bastante para não repetir perguntas aqui, mas realmente não entendo o motivo da instrução SQL funcionar no MySQL Workbench e na string SQL do Java/JDBC não.

Eu tenho duas tabelas ***jogo*** e ***categoria***, e ao listar as categorias eu gostaria de informar a quantidade de jogos cadastrados na respectiva categoria, ex:

Categoria: Ação (**3**) jogos

Categoria: Corrida (**1**) jogos

Categoria: Luta (**1**) jogos

Um relacionamento onde uma categoria tem muitos jogos e cada jogo tem a sua categoria.

Bom, até aí tudo bem. O problema é que antes de inserir o SQL no método `preparedStatement("SQL")` no java eu faço um teste no MySQL Worckbench e o teste me retornou um resultado satisfatório:

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.categoria, COUNT(j.id_categoria) as qtd 
FROM categoria c INNER JOIN jogo j ON c.id = j.id_categoria GROUP BY c.id;
```

Resultado no workbench

```
id   categoria   qtd
1      Ação      3
2     Corrida    1
3      Luta      1
```

Porém com o mesmo SQL no java o resultado é o sequinte:

```
id   categoria   qtd
1      Ação       1
1      Ação       1
1      Ação       1
```

Parte do método `getAll()` da classe `CategoriaDAO`.

```java
PreparedStatement ps = conexao.preparedStatement("SQL_ACIMA");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
List<Categoria> categorias = new ArrayList<>();
while(rs.next()) {
    categoria.setId(rs.getInt("c.id"));
    categoria.setCategoria(rs.getString("c.categoria"));
    categoria.setQtd(rs.getInt("qtd"));
    categorias.add(categoria);
}
return categorias;
```

No JSP:

```xml
<jsp:useBean id="categorias" class="br.com.jogos.CategoriaDAO"></jsp:useBean>
<c:forEach var="cat" items="${categorias.getAll()}">        
    <tr>
        <td>${cat.getCategoria()}</td>
        <td>${cat.getQtd()}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia do motivo da mesma instrução SQL ter dois resultados distintos, eu já agradeço. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PreparedStatement ps = conexao.preparedStatement("SQL_ACIMA");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
List<Categoria> categorias = new ArrayList<>();
while(rs.next()) {
    categoria.setId(rs.getInt("c.id"));
    categoria.setCategoria(rs.getString("c.categoria"));
    categoria.setQtd(rs.getInt("qtd"));
    categorias.add(categoria);
}
return categorias;
```

Observe que você está sempre usando a mesma instância de categoria e não instâncias diferentes! O que você queria era isso:

```
try (
    PreparedStatement ps = conexao.preparedStatement("SQL_ACIMA");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
) {
    List<Categoria> categorias = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Categoria c = new Categoria();
        c.setId(rs.getInt("c.id"));
        c.setCategoria(rs.getString("c.categoria"));
        c.setQtd(rs.getInt("qtd"));
        categorias.add(c);
    }
    return categorias;
}
```

Ah, e lembre-se de usar o [**try-with-resources**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) para gerenciar o `PreparedStatement` e o `ResultSet` adequadamente (e provavelmente o `conexao` também deveria).

Também sugiro utilizar objetos imutáveis com parâmetros passados no construtor. Se tivesse usado essa abordagem, o problema que você tem não teria acontecido. Tenho [**uma resposta sobre isso em uma outra pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/246037/132).

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu tempo e sua resposta!

Comment: @IgorDias Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 